# Export Model For Serving But Tensor Type Dismatch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

#### What related GitHub issues or StackOverflow threads have you found by searching the web for your problem?

I am trying to export the model for serving , but it's report type error about *inputs* tensor.
but in the export and predict part , the **inputs** are the same type.

#### If possible, provide a minimal reproducible example (We usually don't have time to read hundreds of lines of your code)

here is a sample code for my exporting
```

```
    named_graph_signature = {
        'inputs': exporter.generic_signature({
                      'sparse_index': tf.placeholder(tf.int64, name="feature_index")
                      'sparse_ids': tf.placeholder(tf.int64,name = "feature_ids"),
                      'sparse_values':tf.placeholder(tf.int64, name ="feature_values"),
                      'sparse_shape':tf.placeholder(tf.int64, name="feature_shape")
        }),
        'outputs': exporter.generic_signature({
            'prob': inference_softmax
        })}
    model_exporter.init(
        sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
        #default_graph_signature=named_graph_signature,
        named_graph_signatures=named_graph_signature,
        init_op=init_op)
    model_exporter.export(export_path, tf.constant(export_version), sess)
    print('Done exporting!')
```

```

here is my code for predicting

```

```
  ins = "0 142635:1 250810:1 335229:1 375278:1 392970:1 506983:1 554566:1 631968:1 647823:1 658803:1 733446:1 856305:1 868202:1"
  FEATURE_SIZE = 1000000
  tokens = ins.split(" ")
  feature_num = 0
  feature_ids = []
  feature_values = []
  feature_index = []

  for feature in tokens[1:]:
      feature_id, feature_value = feature.split(":")
      feature_ids.append(int(feature_id))
      feature_values.append(float(feature_value))
      feature_index.append([1, feature_num])
      feature_num += 1

  feature_shape = [1, FEATURE_SIZE]

  sparse_index = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(numpy.asarray(feature_index), dtype=tf.int64)
  sparse_ids = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(numpy.asarray(feature_ids), dtype=tf.int64)
  sparse_values = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(numpy.asarray(feature_values), dtype=tf.float32)
  sparse_shape= tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(numpy.asarray(feature_shape), dtype=tf.int64)

  channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, port)
  stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name = model_name
  request.model_spec.version.value = model_version
  print model_name,model_version

  request.inputs['sparse_index'].CopyFrom(sparse_index)
  request.inputs['sparse_ids'].CopyFrom(sparse_ids)
  request.inputs['sparse_values'].CopyFrom(sparse_values)
  request.inputs['sparse_shape'].CopyFrom(sparse_shape)
  # Send request

  result = stub.Predict(request, request_timeout)
```

```

#### Logs or other output that would be helpful

(If logs are large, please upload as attachment or provide link).

```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 59, in main
    result = stub.Predict(request, request_timeout)
  File "/home/serving/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 305, in __call__
    self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
  File "/home/serving/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 203, in _blocking_unary_unary
    raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="input size does not match signature")
```

```

Comment: We have the similar problem for sparse data. It works for dense data and you can find out the complete server and clients in https://github.com/tobegit3hub/deep_recommend_system/ .

Because we use index, ids and values for exporter, they should work just like the dense signature.